# join tables and SUM columns for each distinct row with some rows are considered as column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables as

***table1***

```
id1  | total_amount| final_amount| p_id
---------------------------------------
1    |  500        |    505      |  10
2    |  700        |    710      |  20
3    |  400        |    400      |  10
4    |  450        |    460      |  20
5    |  300        |    300      |  10
```

***table2***

```
id2    | month  | amount | id1
------------------------------
1      |  jan   |  300   |  1
2      |  feb   |  200   |  1
3      |  jan   |  200   |  2
4      |  feb   |  500   |  2
5      |  feb   |  400   |  3
6      |  jan   |  150   |  4
7      |  feb   |  300   |  4
8      |  jan   |  300   |  5
```

here tatal_amount column value is sum(amount) by condition as id1
while final_amount is getting from total_amount+(some dummy value)

so result getting from those table is as below..

```
id3 | p_id  | jan | feb | total
-------------------------------
1   |  10   | 600 | 600 | 1205
2   |  20   | 350 | 800 | 1170
```

here value in jan,feb columns is sum of amount in table2 while value in total column is sum of final_amount in table1 and those all is group by p_id
so what is a query for above output.
if you known then please reply......

Comment: yes obviously it require pivote methods but it require some more to show total by sum of final_amount in table1 and those all is group by p_id

Comment: as i had tried a query as                                          SELECT t1.p_id,
         sum(CASE WHEN t2.month = 'jan' THEN t2.quantity ELSE NULL END) AS "jan",
        sum(CASE WHEN t2.month = 'feb' THEN t2.quantity ELSE NULL END) AS "feb",
sum(t1.final_amount) as "Total"
    FROM table t1 JOIN table t2 ON t1.id1 = t2.id1
GROUP BY t1.p_id    But it showing wrong values in Total column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't state RDBMS.

The following works in SQL Server

```
WITH table1(id1, total_amount, final_amount, p_id)
     AS (SELECT 1,500,505,10 UNION ALL
         SELECT 2,700,710,20 UNION ALL
         SELECT 3,400,400,10 UNION ALL
         SELECT 4,450,460,20 UNION ALL
         SELECT 5,300,300,10),
     table2(id2, month, amount, id1)
     AS (SELECT 1,'jan',300,1 UNION ALL
         SELECT 2,'feb',200,1 UNION ALL
         SELECT 3,'jan',200,2 UNION ALL
         SELECT 4,'feb',500,2 UNION ALL
         SELECT 5,'feb',400,3 UNION ALL
         SELECT 6,'jan',150,4 UNION ALL
         SELECT 7,'feb',300,4 UNION ALL
         SELECT 8,'jan',300,5),
     t1
     AS (SELECT p_id,SUM(final_amount) AS total_amount
         FROM   table1
         GROUP  BY p_id),
     t2
     AS (SELECT p_id,
                SUM(CASE WHEN month = 'jan' THEN amount END) AS jan,
                SUM(CASE WHEN month = 'feb' THEN amount END) AS feb
         FROM   table2
                JOIN table1
                  ON table1.id1 = table2.id1
         GROUP  BY p_id)
SELECT Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS id3,t1.p_id,jan,feb,
       total_amount
FROM   t1
       JOIN t2
         ON t1.p_id = t2.p_id
```

Comment: hi Martin, ref: your answer as query on my question regarding join tables and SUM columns for each distinct row with some rows are considered as column. Question:this query is not run in postgresql. as their is any syntax for query to run in postgresql if YES Reply a Query. thanks